# Web design: "scroll-down navigation"

Tags: web

What is the technique called that is used in some web apps, like http://www.alfredapp.com where the navigation scrolls down the site to reveal another site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get such way of navigation, i would put all of my content on a single page and use a "smooth scroll effect", like the one on [this site](http://pagescroller.com/), to switch between sections.

You will find plenty of more JavaScript (and jQuery) based "smooth scroll effects" by simply googling "[smoth scroll through page sections](https://www.google.de/search?q=building%20a%20single%20page%20app%20with%20sections&oq=building%20a%20single%20page%20app%20with%20sections&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l3.19604&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=smoth%20scroll%20through%20page%20sections&oq=smoth%20scroll%20through%20page%20sections&gs_l=serp.3...258402.269729.2.270121.34.34.0.0.0.0.335.4336.6j26j0j2.34.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.mABc8H_341g&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.Yms&fp=d90d956d33b9db18&biw=1024&bih=511)".

That's how they probably done it on [alfredapp.com](http://www.alfredapp.com) too.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know the name of it, but this is exactly what I was looking for.