# What is the name of that web design?

Tags: html, web

I see this web design everywhere. Basically big clean separated blocks where each block usually takes the height of the screen.

Example: https://www.blueorigin.com/

Does it have a name ? Is it some sort of framework/template ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337515/web-design-scroll-down-navigation. Answer there is a 'smooth scroll' website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, almost one year later :) It is called bootstrap.

http://adventurega.me/bootstrap/
http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

According to CopyScape it seems the the template doesn't match any other websites. My guess would be that people are just starting to use a mobile friendly inspired design and that is a common concept of that design.

It is very effective however :-)